# Image.Save can not over write images in Win7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, system.drawing.imaging

I'm trying to save a image into a local drive using `Image.Save` method. It works fine in other OS but I see only problem in Win7.

In Win7 it can't overwrite existing images, even it does not throw any error. Possibly it's a bug in Win7 as I see a related hot fix here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028610 .

But this hot fix doesn't solve my problem. If anyone have encountered same issue please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you happen to be viewing the result images in an application that might cache them, such as IE?

Comment: Have a look at this answer from another SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340337/how-can-i-get-net-to-save-this-image/2350569#2350569

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of a workaround, but can you delete the existing image first? `System.IO.File.Delete(path)` before the save should give you more info.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need elevated privileges.

See here [Windows 7 and Vista UAC - Programmatically requesting elevation in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282448/windows-7-and-vista-uac-programatically-requesting-elevation-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

What folder are you trying to save it to?  The root folder of your C: drive?  Win7 is fickle about programmitcally saving files to the root folder of a drive.  Try saving it to a folder off of the root and see if that helps.